Azure Synapse CI/CD Pipelines and Migrating SQL Pool State
I am currently working on a project within Azure Synapse Analytics that consists of several pipelines and a dedicated SQL pool that will serve as a data warehouse. I have managed to get a working CI/CD pipeline working within Azure Devops to migrate changes from the "workspace_publish" branch to our UAT environment. The CI/CD pipeline utilizes the Azure SQL Data Warehouse Deployment task to publish the changes from the "workspace_publish" branch.
Everything is working with the exception of updating the state of the SQL pool. I was under the impression that the migration task would handle the updates to the SQL pool given that any database work done within Synapse studio can be captured via source control.

And it appears to execute the SQL script successfully as part of the deployment

However, the changes are not reflected within the UAT SQL pool environment (i.e. I am not seeing the table [dbo].[deleteme] even after refreshing the view in studio).
To be clear the UAT Synapse instance is not connected to source control per the documentation and tutorials that I have read and the only mode that is available is "Synapse live" if that may have bearing on the issue.
Outside of this process for migrating the state of the SQL pool I have encountered others using the DACPAC migration but I have concerns with migrating changes that should not be promoted to UAT/Production given that the SQL pool itself does not abide by version control.
Can anyone provide insight into whether the behavior that I am expecting (the migration of the pool state via the changes captured in the SQL scripts) is the actual behavior of deployment task, and if not, what is the appropriate approach to take to automate the update of the pool.
Thank you in advance for any help.
